# MySQL group by 2 columns, but return in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, greatest-n-per-group

I've seen answers to similar questions but can't find a solution to this problem.

I need to select photo albums, a single photo and user details from three tables. I only want to return the most recent album for each user. I can't find a way of doing this having tried grouping and SELECT DISTINCT queries. Here's my current query, which works fine except that it returns multiple albums from the same user:

```
SELECT 
gallery_albums.title, gallery_albums.siteID, gallery_albums.albumID, gallery_albums.albumDate, gallery_photos.photoID, gallery_albums.userID
FROM gallery_albums, users, gallery_photos
WHERE users.userID = gallery_albums.userID 
AND gallery_photos.albumID = gallery_albums.albumID
GROUP BY gallery_albums.albumID
ORDER BY gallery_albums.albumDate DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

THE WORKING CODE

This is a slight modification of the solution suggested by aarthi_ram

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
       SELECT gallery_albums.title, gallery_albums.siteID, gallery_albums.albumID, gallery_albums.albumDate, gallery_photos.photoID, gallery_albums.userID, users.fName, users.lName
    FROM gallery_albums, users, gallery_photos
    WHERE users.userID = gallery_albums.userID
    AND gallery_photos.albumID = gallery_albums.albumID
    GROUP BY gallery_albums.albumID
    ORDER BY gallery_albums.albumDate DESC  
  ) AS newTable
  GROUP BY userID
  ORDER BY albumDate DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: can you post the structure of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to imagine the schema of your table but I'm guessing that there are *auto_increment column* in each table. And a `user` can have multiple `gallery_albums` as well as it can contains multiple `gallery_photos`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN gallery_albums b
            ON a.userID = b.userID 
        INNER JOIN gallery_photos c
            ON b.albumID = c.albumID 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  userID, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    gallery_albums
            GROUP   BY userID
        ) d ON  b.userID = d.userID AND
                b.ID = d.max_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  albumID, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    gallery_photos
            GROUP   BY albumID
        ) e ON  c.albumID = e.albumID AND
                c.ID = e.max_ID
ORDER   BY b.albumDate DESC
LIMIT   0, 30
```

As you can see, there are columns called `ID` used on the two subqueries: `d` and `e`. These columns are the *auto_incremented column* on each table. If you have dates columns which define their status whether they are recent or not, you can also use it.

Comment: Thank you, this also worked perfectly once I'd changed the column names (sorry I didn't include a schema)! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are looking for the group-wise maximum. There are several ways to solve this problem. In this case something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
gallery_albums.title, gallery_albums.siteID, gallery_albums.albumID, gallery_albums.albumDate, gallery_photos.photoID, gallery_albums.userID
FROM gallery_albums
LEFT JOIN gallery_albums ga2 ON gallery_albums.albumID = ga2.albumID AND gallery_albums.albumDate < ga2.albumDate
JOIN gallery_photos ON gallery_photos.albumID = gallery_albums.albumID
JOIN users ON users.userID = gallery_albums.userID
WHERE ga2.albumID IS NULL
ORDER BY gallery_albums.albumDate DESC
```

The LEFT JOIN on `gallery_albums ga2` combined with the condition `ga2.albumID IS NULL` is what guarantees that you get only the most recent album.

You can find [two other solutions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT 
gallery_albums.title, gallery_albums.siteID, gallery_albums.albumID,gallery_albums.albumDate, gallery_photos.photoID, gallery_albums.userID
FROM gallery_albums, users, gallery_photos
WHERE users.userID = gallery_albums.userID 
AND gallery_photos.albumID = gallery_albums.albumID
GROUP BY gallery_albums.albumID
ORDER BY gallery_albums.albumDate DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30);
```

might work. This will help retrieve the first row from the resultset generated by your query.

Comment: you are mixing `TOP` which is for `SQL Server` and `LIMIT` for `MySQL`.

Comment: This worked with the TOP 1 removed and "AS newTable" added at the end.

Thank you!